# How to hide id input and give it a value in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 models that are related and what i would like to do is in my add view i would like to set the id field as a hidden field so that it doesnt show on my add view, when i set it to hidden the form doesn't submit. Is there a way of passing the id value as a hidden field?

here is my add view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQueryComment'); ?>
<?php echo __('Add It Query Comment'); ?>
<?php
echo $this->Form->hidden('it_query_id');
echo $this->Form->input('comment');
?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

and here is add function for the ItQueries Controller

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$this->ItQuery->create();
if ($this->ItQuery->save($this->request->data)) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query has been saved'));
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
}
$itQueryTypes = $this->ItQuery->ItQueryType->find('list');
$this->set(compact('itQueryTypes'));
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add them in the view form then only to pass them to the controller again.

Try to add those to the data array prior to saving:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->ItQuery->create();
    // add the content before passing it on to the model
    $this->request->data['ItQuery']['it_query_id'] = $id;
    if ($this->ItQuery->save($this->request->data)) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

The form does not have to know about them. And nobody can read them or tamper with them.

See "Default Values – hidden!" at http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

Comment: Nice post, Mark! I haven't been active long on StackOverflow, but more and more I feel the need for some well-written CakePHP tutorials/best practice pages to point people to. (How, and which cache directories to clear, how to enable debug..), will probably save a lot of time when writing answers :)

Comment: @mark if i add this code in my controller     $this->request->data['ItQuery']['it_query_id'] = '$id';

It gives me an error Undefined index: it_query_id

Comment: quite unlikely - is this error supposed to be the same row? also note, that you just put a variable into `''` here.